# How do I augment the cypress TypeScript module?

Tags: typescript, cypress, typescript-typings

The cypress mdoule has `index.d.ts` containing:

```
/// <reference path="./cypress-npm-api.d.ts" />
```

`cypress-npm-api.d.ts` contains:

```
declare module 'cypress' {
  interface CypressNpmApi {
    defineConfig<ComponentDevServerOpts = any>(config: Cypress.ConfigOptions<ComponentDevServerOpts>): Cypress.ConfigOptions
  }
  // export Cypress NPM module interface
  const cypress: CypressNpmApi
  export = cypress
}
```

I tried augmenting this with:

```
import { CustomConfig } from './@cypress/gc-config'
import ConfigOptions = Cypress.ConfigOptions

declare module 'cypress' {
  interface CustomConfigOptions<ComponentDevServerOpts = any> extends ConfigOptions<ComponentDevServerOpts> {
    e2e: EndToEndConfigOptions & CustomConfig
  }

  export function defineConfig<ComponentDevServerOpts = any>(
    config: CustomConfigOptions<ComponentDevServerOpts>
  ): CustomConfigOptions
}
```

When I do:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress'
```

Then this `defineConfig` has the previous signature.

If I rename the module to `cypress2` then it has the correct signature but this is the wrong module name.

My `tsconfig.json` is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // Silly dayjs needs this as it's ESM types are wrong.
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    // Required for cypress-terminal-report.
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["ESNext"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    // This has to be ES2019. See https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/20753
    "target": "ES2019",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "types": [
      "cypress",
      "cypress-plugin-stripe-elements",
      "@percy/cypress",
      "@testing-library/cypress"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "types",
      "node_modules",
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@utils/*": ["cypress/utils/*"],
      "@fixtures/*": ["cypress/fixtures/*"],
      // The same alias exists in cypress.config.ts for the .js side of things.
      "@protobuf/*": ["protobuf/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

Why doesn't it work? What do I do to try and diagnose what the problem is?